# I can't install nginx 1.22.1 from the official repository

Tags: nginx, repository, oracle-linux

I have a VM on Oracle Linux 8.8
I need to install nginx-1.22.1, but only version nginx-1.14.1 can be installed from the official repository:

```
https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/appstream/x86_64/index.html
```

This version nginx-1.22.1 is present in this repository.
Also this repository is enabled:

```
[ol8_appstream]
name=Oracle Linux 8 Application Stream ($basearch)
baseurl=https://yum$ociregion.$ocidomain/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/appstream/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

I have executed the commands:

```
yum clean all
yum makecache
```

But after executed:

```
yum install nginx
```

the yum manager can only install version 1.14.1:

```
nginx     x86_64     1:1.14.1-9.0.1.module+el8.0.0+5347+9282027e
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To check the available Module versions:

```
# dnf module list | grep -i nginx
nginx                1.14 [d][e]     common [d]                               nginx webserver
nginx                1.16            common [d]                               nginx webserver
nginx                1.18            common [d]                               nginx webserver
nginx                1.20            common [d]                               nginx webserver
nginx                1.22            common [d]                               nginx webserver
```

Hint: [d]efault, [e]nabled, [x]disabled, [i]nstalled

2. Reset the module if already enabled:

`# dnf module reset nginx`

3. To enable the module with required version:

`# dnf module enable nginx:1.22`

4. To update the module package with required version:

`# dnf update nginx`

5. To install the module package with required version:

`# dnf install nginx`

Answer (score 1):

Oracle decide this is stable enough version for production and this is the reason they do not provide next version(s) and do not update the repo index file. But you can always install from nginx.org repo. Here is the path to RPM files: https://nginx.org/packages/rhel/8/x86_64/RPMS/

And you can install it via command:

```
yum localinstall https://nginx.org/packages/rhel/8/x86_64/RPMS/nginx-1.22.1-1.el8.ngx.x86_64.rpm
```

Or you can try to install directly from Oracle repo:

```
yum localinstall https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/appstream/x86_64/getPackage/nginx-1.22.1-1.0.1.module+el8.8.0+21016+51077804.x86_64.rpm
```